# why there is "ï»¿" when doing file comparison

Tags: perforce

in the beginning of the file when doing diff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UTF-8 file being interpreted as Windows-1252. Those three symbols are the UTF-8 BOM when displayed as bytes in Windows-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

This is the UTF-8 signature (U+FEFF, aka. BOM: Byte Order Mark). Your editor has put it into the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that when the content-encoding is set to something other than UTF8 and the file has been written in utf-8

in php, i used iconv to convert between the types